# Google Sheets multiple formulas

Tags: worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I'm attempting to use the following formulas in one cell. They all work separately, but I can't figure out how to combine them. Can someone help please?

```
=IF(G14="A",H14,"") 
=IF (H14="A", G14,"") 
Otherwise =SUM(G14+H14)
```

Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Could you explain a bit about what the expected output is? You can nest IF statements but im not sure what your end goal is here

EDIT:

Gotcha I think this should do it..

```
=SUM(IF(G14="A", 0, G14) + IF(H14="A", 0, H14))
```

This way your just summing the result of the two if statements. They check if the cell = 'A' and if so setting the value to 0, else they use the actual value of the cell.

Comment: Hi - I'm trying to add two cells (G14 and H14) for a total. Either cell will be entered as number or the letter A. I want to count the letter A as zero OR disregard the cell if it has an A so that the total (in a separate cell) can default to a number.

Comment: @RachaelFolkman Check and see if my above edit works for you

Comment: Amazing!! Thank you SO much for your help! I am learning nesting, etc. It worked perfectly.

Comment: If you have the `+` there is no need for the `SUM()` wrapper.  If you want to use SUM replace the `+` with `,`

Comment: @ScottCraner Your so right! =IF(G14="A", 0, G14) + IF(H14="A", 0, H14) is a simpler answer.

Comment: That's great! Thanks @ScottCraner

Comment: I have another multiple formula I need help with. I'm trying to add a weekly goal total for 5 days. If one of the cells is zero I'd like it to not count as a day. So far I have this:  =SUM(I13,M13,Q13,U13,Y13)   Thoughts?

Comment: @RachaelFolkman new questions get new post, but look into SUMIFS()

Comment: One more question for the original problem I was having. I've now used the suggested formula - if I wanted the cell to say "A" if both the G14 and H14 cells said "A", could I also embed this into the current formula: =SUM(IF(G14="A", 0, G14) + IF(H14="A", 0, H14)) OR Scotts: =IF(G14="A", 0, G14) + IF(H14="A", 0, H14)    Thank you!